# How to work with shopify API level webhook using Rails

Tags: shopify

I'm new to Shopify app development, I just started an app using Rails where I wanted to use Webhooks.
I need to do some action when Order is placed in the Shop.

some one please help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: I'ts pretty straightforward. http://docs.shopify.com/api/webhook In your admin under notifications you select a data type & trigger and enter the URL to push the data to.

Comment: Thanks for replay, I am looking for the API level Webhooks, I think you are talking about the Admin level Webhooks.